How to apply equal indentation to multi-line log entry in log4net?
I want to add equal indentation in log file which is currently showing entries like below. I am using default Log4net appender which gives result like this.

but I want it to be look like below as it is more readable.

I am using Log4net for logging. I am not sure if default PatternLayout has ability to manage the logs.

In  this question they have extended the functionality to be able to indent it. Mabe this works for you too.
